# Make local scanner a network scanner?

Tags: remote, scanning

I have a Canon MP530 attached to my PC. Other PCs in the house can print to this printer (when my PC and the printer are switche don) but I need the MP530 to scan, and send files to other PCs.

At the moment when someone scans something on the Canon MP530, they press the Scan button and a dialog appears on the local PC prompting action. The scan then puts a file (TIFF/JPG/PDF etc) on the local PC.

Instead, what I need is for someone to press the Scan button on the Canon MP530 then a dialog box appears on all network PCs and then the scanning and scanned file ends up on those PCs.

Am I asking too much for a local printer/scanner?

Comment: Your best bet is to share the folder the scanner scans to then map the drives to the other PC's as persistent network shares. There are remote scan software options, Remotescan by Dell is one of them but I believe a single license is around $500 and are generally used in the medical/banking industry to scan documents to a terminal server/citrix environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best (and cheapest) way I can see to accomplish this would be to hook the scanner to a computer that is on most of the time (desktop) and then share the folder it scans to. Then just map the share as a persistent network drive on the other computers, that way the other PC's will reconnect and map the drive when they turn on.

I don't know what operating system you have so I will do this for Windows 7 which is close enough for 8 and vista as well.

So if you have a folder you scan to, C:\scans for example, you can right click> properties then click sharing (not advanced sharing as the standard sharing will set NTFS permissions for you as well) type everyone and click add. You should now have sharing and NTFS permission set to read for everyone, this shouldn't be an issue if your network is behind NAT. However you can also set it to specific user then specify the credentials when you map the drive.

Now on the other PC's (again assuming windows) right click "My computer" and click "Map Network Drive", pick a letter further down the alphabet so it doesn't interfere with any PNP devices. For folder type `\\yourpcname\folder` the PC name can be found under properties after you right click my computer and the folder name is the same name it has on the host PC so in our example: "scans". The first checkbox "Reconnect at logon" will make sure this drive remaps any time this PC logs on and the host is also online, the other checkbox is for using credentials if you don't want your share readable by everyone.

Comment: This is a good workaround too!

Answer (score 0):

Usually the printer ships with a CD that will contain software to allow it to be remotely used. AFAIK, windows does not provide this type of functionality for scanners. The scanner needs to support either remote file transfers, or SMB type file placement. Have you tried logging into the scanner via it's IP address (if it has one)?.